# Returning Set Value in Java [basics]

Tags: java

I really hate to be asking stupid questions, but I have an assignment due which involves some basic lab stuff. I must be missing something important because I was always used to creating instances this way:

```
DVD dvd2 = new DVD("Song Bird","Blues", "Eva Cassidy");
```

But my lecturer wants us to create it this way:

```
   DVD dvd1 = new DVD(); // CALL THE DVD CLASS TO CREATE A NEW INSTANCE OF OBJECT DVD
dvd1.setTitle("Song Bird"); // INITIALIZE TITLE / Set A VALUE
dvd1.setGenre("Blues");
dvd1.setArtist("Eva Cassidy");
```

What am I missing? I presume I need to return the 3 setter values, something like this:

```
  DVD dvd1 = new DVD(String Title, String Genre, String Artist); // CALL THE DVD CLASS TO CREATE A NEW INSTANCE OF OBJECT DVD
    dvd1.setTitle("Song Bird"); // INITIALIZE TITLE / Set A VALUE
    dvd1.setGenre("Blues");
    dvd1.setArtist("Eva Cassidy");
    Return setTitle;
    Return setGenre;
    Return setArtist;
```

Any pointers to tutorials or suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Why did you add all the return methods there? `return dvd1;` - Your version initializes the fields in the constructor, your lecturer has asked you to **not** do that - and instead use `setter`(s) and an empty constructor.

Comment: Thank you, I'm only new to this whole thing. Is there a good tutorial that covers this sort of stuff that you maybe able to point to? There is no point in me asking for the code itself if I still don't understand it.

Comment: Are you really asking about _getter_ methods?

Comment: Yes cause I am new to programming. I'm wasn't born all knowing unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Java class DVD like this

```
class DVD
{
String Title;
String Genre; 
String Artist;

public void setTitle(String s)
{
Title=s;
}

public void setGenre(String s)
{
Genre=s;
}

public void setArtist(String s)
{
Artist=s;
}

}
```

Now , create a object of DVD class in main class and call all the three methods as follows.

```
DVD dvd1=new DVD();
dvd1.setTitle("Song Bird"); 
dvd1.setGenre("Blues");
dvd1.setArtist("Eva Cassidy");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got sorted in the end!

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of using the overloaded constructor, you use default constructor. Try this:

```
DVD dvd1 = new DVD();
dvd1.setTitle("Song Bird");
dvd1.setGenre("Blues");
dvd1.setArtist("Eva Cassidy");
return dvd1;
```

Also, if you give me more details for the question, I think I can answer better.